# What is the relation between p and k if p + |k| > |p| + k?

Tags: inequality

If p and k are some real numbers, then what is the relation between them
if p + |k| > |p| + k

Comment: I'm guessing that one of those $p$'s should be a $q$?

Comment: i have changed the question. thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $k\geq 0$, then $|k|=k$ and we have $p>|p|$ which is impossible. So $k<0$ and $k=-|k|$. We have
$$
p+|k|>|p|-|k|\implies p-|p|>-2|k|.
$$
Clearly any $p\geq 0$ works. If $p<0$ then $p=-|p|$ and we have $-2|p|>-2|k|$ and so $|p|<|k|$.

In conclusion, we have $k<0$ and $p>k$.

---

**Alternatively**: let $f(x)=|x|-x$. Then $f$ is strictly positive and *decreasing* on $(-\infty,0)$ and is $f=0$ on $[0,\infty).$ We are given that $f(k)>f(p)$. It must be the case that $k<0$ and $p>k$.